# An error occured while communicating to the server (jquery alert)

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc, jquery-jtable

I am working on an application using spring mvc and jquery.

I am getting this error message while selecting another tab and the previous tab is not loaded properly, and only for a fraction of seconds the alert shows up and I am redirected to the requested page.

I have checked the required jquery jtable libraries and everything's getting loaded properly.
The capitalization for JSON is also done.

Then where does the problem persist?

Please help me to find out.

Comment: Are you doing ajax stuff for tab clicks?

Comment: yes. ajax is being used.

Comment: I guess then that it is simple , when you are clicking on one tab, the content is being fetched fro server in the mean time you are clicking on another tab and the previous ajax call could not be completed, is this the issue?

Comment: yes.. by aborting one request i am getting this error messag for a sec and then redirected to the requested page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess then that it is simple , when you are clicking on one tab, the content is being fetched fro server in the mean time you are clicking on another tab and the previous ajax call could not be completed.
So the solution would be to disable all tab clicks while your ajax calls are being processed:

```
$(".your_Tab_class").removeClass('.class_name_assigned_To_click_event');
```

When the ajax calls have been completed,re-assign the click events based on class name

```
  $('.your_Tab_class').each(function(){
          $(this).addClass('.class_name_assigned_To_click_event'); 
    });
```

Comment: yes this will work
. even i was thinking of masking the page but suppose i want to redirect to the new requested page, As I have clicked the tab by mistake, then disabling tab click will not help..

Comment: You can have this js as common in all the pages that have tabs involved?

Comment: so my question is other than disabling the click there is no solution.

Comment: There are other solutions, but based upon if the other pages are not heavy to load you can load them in the same page.... :)